# Loop through radio buttons and change background color on the closest div, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a 6 x 8 grid essentially of radio buttons under the same name 'tselect'. When the page loads, I want all of them to run a command similar to this one

```
$(this).closest('div').addClass('highlight', 300);
```

Basically change the background color of the closest div by adding a new div class on top. I tried doing a for loop to go through all of them, but the jquery command wasn't executing. Any ideas?

Edit: Adding Code...

```
<div id="sch_cal">
                <div id="sch_cal_column">
                    <div id="sch_cal_row">
                        <div id="sch_cal_time"><p class="ctime">8:00am</p></div>
                        <div style="height: 100%"><input class="ctime" type="radio" name="tselect"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sch_cal_row">
                        <div id="sch_cal_time"><p class="ctime">8:20am</p></div>
                        <div style="height: 100%"><input class="ctime" type="radio" name="tselect"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sch_cal_row">
                        <div id="sch_cal_time"><p class="ctime">8:40am</p></div>
                        <div style="height: 100%"><input class="ctime" type="radio" name="tselect"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sch_cal_row">
                        <div id="sch_cal_time"><p class="ctime">9:00am</p></div>
                        <div style="height: 100%"><input class="ctime" type="radio" name="tselect"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sch_cal_row">
                        <div id="sch_cal_time"><p class="ctime">9:20am</p></div>
                        <div style="height: 100%"><input class="ctime" type="radio" name="tselect"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sch_cal_row">
                        <div id="sch_cal_time"><p class="ctime">9:40am</p></div>
                        <div style="height: 100%"><input class="ctime" type="radio" name="tselect"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sch_cal_row">
                        <div id="sch_cal_time"><p class="ctime">10:00am</p></div>
                        <div style="height: 100%"><input class="ctime" type="radio" name="tselect"/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sch_cal_row">
                        <div id="sch_cal_time"><p class="ctime">10:20am</p></div>
                        <div style="height: 100%"><input class="ctime" type="radio" name="tselect"/></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide your HTML code and what you have already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to highlight the nearest div, perhaps you need something like:

```
$(this).closest('div').effect("highlight", {}, 300);
```

If you are looking to change the background color, you can try:

```
$(this).closest('div').css( "background-color" , "red" )
```

or

```
$(this).closest('div').addClass('highlight');
```

[addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) doesn't take second argument as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$('input[type="radio"].ctime').closest('div').addClass('highlight');
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z7FtQ/1/)

You have multiple elements with same id `sch_cal_row` and `sch_cal_time` that is invalid, id should be unique.